# PHP scraping to extract the price of items

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have tried to create a **PHP** code to extract the price of items from an eCommerce website. I created a variable where I need to type in the URL of the item and the code will fetch the price of the item and then will display it.

Unfortunately I have tried it for more than 20 times but still I am not getting the result. I went to my professor and he said, he is really busy and will try to find the solution after 3 days. I don't want to wait for 3 days.

Can anyone please help me?

I have been trying the fetch the price of this [item](http://www.flipkart.com/lg-g2-16-gb/p/itmdzuhncfhj9zwt?pid=MOBDZUHGWZ3HMCMF&ref=c35ae3ed-99d5-49d8-ae45-b0d4de3afe41)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Think for a moment: what help do you expect from us? Do you want us to tell you which lines are not implemented correctly in your code? If the logic is not right? Fine, but how do you expect us to point those mistakes out _if you don't show us your code_ ? I know you're in a hurry and frustrated by your professor, but really, how could we be of some help? Do we need to guess it or mind-read you? Or do you want a ready made working script so you throw your out (if it exists)?

Answer (score 1):

You must try something before coming to Stack Overflow. I hope you won't do this mistake again ;)

Well.. enough of my advice. Here i wrote this code using **`cURL`** on **PHP**. Gets you the amount **40490**.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.flipkart.com/lg-g2-16-gb/p/itmdzuhncfhj9zwt?pid=MOBDZUHGWZ3HMCMF&ref=c35ae3ed-99d5-49d8-ae45-b0d4de3afe41');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$strx=strip_tags(curl_exec($ch));
$str_key="Rs. ";
$end_key=" Inclusive";
$strt=strpos($strx,$str_key);
$end=strpos($strx,$end_key);

echo intval(substr($strx,$strt+strlen($str_key),9));//outputs 40490 (price of the prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function scrapeProductPrice($remote_page_content,$log){
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();   
        $dom->loadHTML($remote_page_content);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $my_xpath_query = "//table//tr";
        $result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);
        foreach($result_rows as $key => $value) {
            $lookUp = strstr($value->nodeValue, PRODUCT_NAME) ? str_split($value->nodeValue, strlen(PRODUCT_NAME)) : 0;
            if($lookUp){ 
                return $lookUp[1];
            }   
        }
    }
```

Note:Change $remote_page_content with the page url